# Scala pattern-matching on arbitrary case class

Tags: scala

Can you pattern match on an arbitrary case class at runtime (w/o using reflection)? Something like:

```scala
someObj match {
    case cc: AnyCaseClass =>
        println("This is a case class")
        cc.copy() // e.g., all case classes have a copy method
    case other =>
        println("This is not a case class")
        other
}
```

I know case classes implement `Product` and `Serializable`, but those don't include the `copy()` method (and probably are missing other common elements).

Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't and even if you could have access to that `copy` you do not know which fields and types do it has. - What is the meta-problem you want to solve? is probably that you want either a **Typeclass**, some generic programming using **Shapeless** / **Magnolia** or a custom **macro**, but is hard to tell without more context.

Comment: The case classes don't really "have" copy method. Its a compile time only method and the compiler needs to know the exact type of the operant.

Comment: @texasbruce `javap` says otherwise, `scalac` generates `copy` method and `copy$default$argNo` for each argument (`argNo=1,2,3,...`). It's a method synthesized by compiler and pretty much existing in the bytecode.

Comment: @ishovelwell `copy` has a different arity for each `case class`, there is no one common interface which would allow that. The fact that each `copy` is the same name is more of a convention demanded by specification than a contract enforced by implementing interfaces. And on bytecode level you almost never have `.copy()` method - default arguments are something that exist only in `scalac`, on bytecode level this is a normal method (`.copy(args)`) where defaults are results returned by some `method$default$argNo` methods. You could call them by runtime reflection but it would be a pain.

Comment: It will help us if you write what you try to achieve as calling `copy()` (nothing overriden) on an immutable value is virtually equal to returning that value instead. You would need some exotic situation to actually require such setup.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez the `copy` explanation makes sense, thanks. We are considering applying some dynamic transformations using bytebuddy to a set of classes (why we might have to do that is a long story). Anyways, this set of classes is unknown--and we can't build against them--but if it's (1) a case class, and (2) implements a particular interface, we want to transform it. So I was just looking for the cleanest way to determine (1) in isolation. However, when taking both (1) and (2) together, matching on `SomeInterface with Product with Serializable` is probably sufficient for our needs.

Comment: Dude that sounds like a nightmare, I guess traditional solutions like a **typeclass** is out of scope, but if this is a compile time then probably something using **Shapeless** or **Magnolia** may be possible since those let you abstract over the case class structure. If not, maybe a custom **macro**. Anyways, good luck!